# GitHubで第三者が気軽にIssue登録しても大丈夫ですか？

Tags: github, oss

当方オープンソースの開発には参加したことがありません。
あるレポジトリで自分が実装できそうもない機能の開発を依頼したいのですが
こういうのって第三者が気軽に登録してもいいものなのでしょうか。
（アホな質問ですみません。）

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- いくつかのリポジトリでは `CONTRIBUTING` というファイルや `README` というファイルに、機能追加を要望したい場合のやり方が書いてあります。GitHub への issue 登録以外の方法をとっているソフトウェアもあるので、もしあればそちらを参考にすると良いです。
- 何も書かれておらず、ソースコードが GitHub で管理されているのであれば、issue を登録するので良いでしょう。Issue を登録したからといってそれが必ずしも実装されることになるとは限りませんが、意見を募ることはできます。できれば「なぜその機能が必要なのか」が具体的に書かれているとありがたいかなと思います。

Answer (score 6):

いいですよ。ただし、それを実装するかどうかはそのOSSの開発者次第なので、その機能が必要と思われなければ、そのままスルー（最終的にはクローズ）されると思いますが。